# How can I force Rails to always use the texts from de.yml regardless of user locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Is there a way to force Rails to always use the texts from de.yml, regardless of what the user's locale is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rails guide is helpful. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

To begin with:

> If you want to translate your Rails application to a single language other than English (the default locale), you can set I18n.default_locale to your locale in application.rb or an initializer as shown above, and it will persist through the requests.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-the-locale

Okay, but we want not just the default locale, but to insist on this regardless of user's locale? No problem, that'll happen already (I think), if you just *don't* implement the code that's next in the guide to set the current locale to be user specific.

Comment: You are right. However I had to add ```I18n.default_locale = 'pt-BR'``` even though I had ```config.i18n.default_locale = 'pt-BR'``` on application.rb.

Comment: weird! bug in rails I guess, or else us just not entirely understand what's up. glad you got it figured out.

Comment: oh wait, the rails guide actually SAYS that, and recommends setting I18n.default_locale, so, okay, great!